# Angular - Udefined value when trying get value of option value from a html select tag

Tags: html, typescript, events, html-select

I want to get the value when change the selected option in a select tag in my angular component:

```
<select name="types" class="custom-select form-control rounded" (change)="changeType($event.target.value)">
  <option selected value="allTypes">Tous</option>
  <option *ngFor="let type of types; let i = index" [value]="types.id">
   {{types[i].name}
  </option>
</select>
```

---

```
  changeType(type) {
    this.chosenType = type
    console.log('changed type', type)
    this.getData()
  }
```

when log selected type I got undefined !

Answer (score 0):

using **ngValue** solve the problem